# How to set up ContainerViewController frame?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicontainerview

I have ContainerViewController that has two childviewcontrollers.So with segues I am calling child view controller that I want to show.My problem is that childviewcontroller are not same size so I am having problem of size of container view.I am not using Autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution but to:

1. get advantage of the size inspector in the interface builder as much as you can.
   In most cases I managed to get subviews resized and moved based on the container view. for some applications I also used a single ViewController for iPhone and iPad without using AutoLayout.
2. Things that can't be done with the first point. resize and position it with code. in your child controller implement a method that do that. Call it after you init you child controllers.

in ContainerViewController:

```
childViewContainer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
```

or the opposite:

```
self.view.frame = childViewContainer.view.frame;
```